# How can I make a bootable partition to run XP.iso from USB stick in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, installation, multi-boot, liveusb

I have a 16GB USB stick, and I am on Ubuntu 13.04 OS. I want to place XP.iso into one of the partitions and then use it to install XP from within USB stick. I searched for the web but I didn't find a reliable guide for Linux OSs. Would anybody here direct me on the right path?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can boot XP `ISO` directly from USB without unpacking using `grub4dos`. I have done it myself. It is not very straightforward but it definitely can be done. The trick is to boot into grub4dos and then load entire iso into RAM. You will also need an image of boot disk that will act as boot floppy.

If you want to achieve it all in a simple way, I recommend using YUMI, (please do not consider this as advertising). Visit original developers [website](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and download installer. Then all you will need is XP `ISO` and a pendrive.

Be careful though and follow instructions precisely as booting XP `ISO` is different then generic `ISO` boot.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can't boot XP setup directly from USB flash IIRC, but you can make USB flash DOS-bootable and put (extract) ISO contents (files) there. Then you'll be able to [start XP Setup from DOS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307848).

How to create DOS bootable flash from Linux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/176141/how-to-create-dos-boot-usb-flash-drive-with-xubuntu